# Unable to fetch ID from one sheet and write to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have two Excel workbooks.

First Workbook has two sheets: "Sales" and "Lookup".

Second Workbook has one sheet: "ID"

From the first workbook (Sales), I have to read column 'B' values, search it in column A of "Lookup" sheet and get name from column B.

After fetching ID, I have to write to column E of "ID" workbook.

I tried the first part, but it is not iterating through the cells of Sales and not picking value from "Lookup".

```
Sub btnExport_Click()
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim MyStringVar1 As String

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lookup")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales")
Set rng = ws2.Range("B2")

With ws2
    On Error Resume Next 'add this because if value is not found, vlookup fails
    MyStringVar1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Left(rng, 6), ws1.Range("A2:C65536").Value, 2, False)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If MyStringVar1 = "" Then MsgBox "Item not found" Else MsgBox MyStringVar1
End With

End Sub
```

***  Edited ***

Code fixed. It is now reading from first cell of Sales but not iterating. Also, while iterating and fetching from Lookup, it has to write to another workbook. This I am not able to fix.

Comment: Why are you using `ActiveSheet`?

Comment: @BigBen Just found a sample and tried. No experience with Macros.

Comment: Add a `Debug.Print i` before the loop to see what the value of `i` actually is.

Comment: @BigBen I have modified the code. It is working but not iterating through sales.

Comment: It's not iterating because you got rid of the loop.

Comment: @BigBen Oh yes. My silly mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two changes that you should make to start. First, try not to reference `ActiveSheet` (as mentioned in the comments). If the macro is run while a different sheet is selected, then it will mess things up. Store the appropriate worksheet in a variable, such as:
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sales")

The other item that stands out is in your loop, you are using the `.Cells` off of the `rng` object. In your case, you set `rng` to be the used range in Column B. Let's assume that's cells B2:B10. When you then say `rng.Cells(i, 2)`, if actually offset to the second column of the range, which starts with Column B. You end up using column C.

Instead, try something like

```
Sub btnExport_Click()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("sales")
    With ws
        Set rng = .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

        For i = 2 To rng.Rows.Count
            .Cells(i, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Cells(i, 1), Sheets("Lookup").Range("A:B"), 2, False)
            MsgBox (.Cells(i, 2))
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @RKh It might be an oversight, but you actually got rid of the `For` loop

Comment: Thanks. BTW, how to address the second part of writing to another workbook.

Comment: @Rkh You'd have to bring the other workbook into scope. Look into the `Workbook.Open(...)` method. Once available, create a reference to the destination worksheet, and then loop down, adding the values. It might be better served as a separate post.